# Using the right Perl array references with IPC::Run

Tags: perl, perl-ipc-run

I'm trying to get this Perl code to work correctly and I believe I just need to get my references right. I would appreciate any feedback on how to use references, but if this code can't be made to work without API changes I would also appreciate feedback on how to change the surrounding APIs to support the data types I need.

I'm trying to add a new test to the PostgreSQL test suite. The code in question runs a subprocess and stores the process arguments in an array literal in a hash. for example:

```
my %pgdump_runs = (
    defaults => {
        dump_cmd => [
            'pg_dump', '--no-sync',
            '-f',      "$tempdir/defaults.sql",
            'postgres',
        ],
    },
    # and others
)
```

That array gets passed to a helper library like so:

```
    $node->command_ok(\@{ $pgdump_runs{$run}->{dump_cmd} },
        "$run: pg_dump runs");
```

The helper library keeps passing the array down:

```
sub command_ok
{
    my ($cmd, $test_name) = @_;
    my $result = run_log($cmd);
```

and then finally calling [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run):

```
sub run_log
{
    return IPC::Run::run(@_);
}
```

To write my test case I **have** to pipe the output of a command to a file descriptor that does not support seeking. It looks like the IPC::Run module supports piping for you. Here's the example for the docs:

```
run \@cmd1, '|', \@cmd2;
```

But I tried a bunch of different ways to try and structure my array literal and none of them worked. For example, I tried this and I believe it gave me an `ARRAY(0xFFFFFFFF)` error:

```
        dump_cmd => [
            ['pg_dump', 'db'],
            '|',
            ['pg_restore', 'db2'],
        ],
```

How can I get this code to set up multiple sub-processes with piping?

UPDATE: I tried out ikegami's suggestion: the `command_ok` function can only have two arguments passed to it, so that doesn't work (you have to pass an array reference for the first argument).

UPDATE: turning on IPC:Run's debug functionality I can see how it's trying to interpret my command line. Instead of dereferencing the array it's trying to stringify (?) it and exec that string as an executable:

```
1070 IPC::Run 0002 01234567890- [#11(59856)]: parsing [ 'ARRAY(0x7ff3016f1090)', '|', 'ARRAY(0x7ff3016f1510)', '>/Users/david/src/pg_bug/postgres/foo' ]
```

Comment: How is `$node->command_ok()` defined? Can it only take an array reference as parameter?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes, unfortunately, it has to take two arguments only. I've updated the question with some more information.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively doing the following:<sup>[1]</sup>

```perl
my %pgdump_runs = (
    foo => {
        dump_cmd => [
            ['pg_dump', 'db'],
            '|',
            ['pg_restore', 'db2'],
        ],
    },
);

IPC::Run::run( $pgdump_runs{foo}{dump_cmd} )
```

This passes a single argument to `run`, but you indicated you wanted to achieve something analogous to

```perl
run \@cmd1, '|', \@cmd2;
```

That would require

```perl
IPC::Run::run( @{ $pgdump_runs{foo}{dump_cmd} } )
```

---

A few ways you can fix this:

1. Replace

   ```perl
   return IPC::Run::run(@_);
   ```

   with

   ```perl
   return IPC::Run::run(@{ $_[0] });
   ```
2. Replace

   ```perl
   run_log($cmd);
   ```

   with

   ```perl
   run_log(@$cmd);
   ```
3. Replace

   ```perl
   sub command_ok {
       my ($cmd, $test_name) = @_;
       my $result = run_log($cmd);
   }

   $node->command_ok(\@{ $pgdump_runs{$run}->{dump_cmd} }, "$run: pg_dump runs");
   ```

   with

   ```perl
   sub command_ok {
       my $test_name = shift;
       my $result = run_log(@_);
   }

   $node->command_ok("$run: pg_dump runs", @{ $pgdump_runs{$run}{dump_cmd} });
   ```
4. Replace

   ```perl
   dump_cmd => [
       ['pg_dump', 'db'],
       '|',
       ['pg_restore', 'db2'],
   ],
   ```

   with

   ```perl
   use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

   dump_cmd => join(' ',
       shell_quote('pg_dump', 'db'),
       '|',
       shell_quote('pg_restore', 'db2'),
   ),
   ```

---

Footnotes:

1. Unless you are trying to autovivify (which you're not),

   ```perl
   \@{ $pgdump_runs{$run}->{dump_cmd} }
   ```

   can also be written as

   ```perl
   $pgdump_runs{$run}->{dump_cmd}
   ```

   And in both cases, the `->` can be omitted because it's between two indexes.

Comment: This did not work. I was missing some helpful information about how the internal functions work. Please read the updated question.

Comment: Your update simply confirms my supposition that you were passing a single value to `run`. My answer still stands (though I've adjusted it to account for the new details).